# appending in loop and add list to a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I run a loop and append data into a list. I failed to convert the list to a data frame in the loop and only able to fix that in a later step and turn every 3 columns into a new row. I was wondering if I can transform a list into a data frame during the loop session.

```
data1<- setNames(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5),20,5)), c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5"))
data2<- setNames(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5),20,3)), c("V1", "V2", "V3"))

library(minerva)
test <- function () {
    result <- NULL
    for (x in 1:3) {
      for (y in 1:2) {
        pair <- as.matrix(cbind(data1[x],data2[y]))
        pair.name1<- mictools(pair)$pval$Var1
        pair.name2<- mictools(pair)$pval$Var2
        pair.p.value <- mictools(pair)$pval$pval
        result <- rbind(result,pair.name1, pair.name2, pair.p.value)
      }}
    result
    }
test.run <- test()
data<- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(test.run, use.names=FALSE),ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))
colnames(data)<- c("TraitA", "TraitB", "P.value")
```

output

```
 Trait A     TraitB    P.value
 R1           V1       9.233e-5
 R1           V2       9.233e-4
 ...............................
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: It is strongly urged to avoid calling `rbind` inside `for` loop which leads to excessive copying in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a list of data frames then `rbind` **once** outside the loop:

```r
test <- function() {
    # INITIALIZE LIST WITH LENGTH
    results <- vector(length=3*2, mode="list")

    n = 1
    for (x in 1:3) {
        for (y in 1:2) {
            pair <- as.matrix(cbind(data1[x], data2[y]))
     
            # ITERATIVELY ASSIGN
            results[[n]] <- data.frame(
                "Trait A" = mictools(pair)$pval$Var1,
                "Trait B" = mictools(pair)$pval$Var2,
                "P.value" = mictools(pair)$pval$pval
            ) 
            n = n + 1
        }
    }

    return(rbind.data.frame(results))
}

data <- test()
```

Alternatively, avoid the bookkeeping of the `list` management and flatten your loops with an apply function like `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`):

```r
# INITIALIZE LIST WITH LENGTH
test <- function(x, y){
    pair <- as.matrix(cbind(data1[x], data2[y]))
     
    data.frame(
        "Trait A" = mictools(pair)$pval$Var1,
        "Trait B" = mictools(pair)$pval$Var2,
        "P.value" = mictools(pair)$pval$pval
    ) 
}
# ALL PAIRWISE COMBINATIONS BETWEEN VECTORS
parms <- expand.grid(x=1:3, y=1:2)

# ELEMENT-WISE LOOP
results <- Map(test, parms$x, parms$y)
data <- rbind.data.frame(results)
```